# Помогите пожалуйста сделать маленький функционал для калькулятора на vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, scss

Помогите пожалуйста сделать функционал на vue.js! У меня есть калькулятор. Заказчик попросил сделать что бы при нажатии и выборе определенного элемента из списка, появлялись несколько картинок(цветов), которую можно выбрать и в процессе отправить на почту как название! сделать список section и отправить его не проблема. Но вопрос в том что бы каждый раздел из списка и у него свои несколько картинок с названием. И это название должно быть привязано к тому или иному списку из выпадающего section.
на примере мой калькулятор countrywood.ru . Вот такой , только при выпадающем меню одного из них появлялись выборы картинок которые можно нажать и так же отправить на почту вместе с остальными даными!

Comment: у верстальшика проблемы со стилями http://prntscr.com/wlwift

Comment: с помощю div-ov выпадающих можно сделать это, как вам вариант?